# Dynamic LINQ Group By Query in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm wondering how to best tackle this, since what I have now works great for a hard-coded column in my view -- I'm wondering how I can extend it to allow the column to be dynamic.

CONTROLLER:

```
var dc = new DataContextDC();
return View(dc.items.Where(i=>i.IsPublic == true));
```

VIEW:

```
<% foreach (var grp in Model.GroupBy(s => s.GroupColumn)) { %>
    <%= Html.Encode(grp.Key) %>
    <% foreach (var item in grp) { %>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Title) %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

As stated, the objective is to let the user choose which column replaces "GroupColumn" above. I'd like to avoid adding any external libraries, etc.

I see using reflection (slow, but fully dynamic) or since this is one View in my application, I just duplicate the above code for each column in the database and then put a switch statement on it (quick, and dirty, but effective)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the kind of thing that you're going to want to use the Linq [Dynamic Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library included with the C# Linq samples.  That way, you can write the query like this:

```
var groups = Model.GroupBy("SomeColumn, SomeOtherColumn")
```

...which is a great deal easier to manage if you're accepting column names from the user - most likely all you have are the column names as strings, and this library will automatically parse those out into lambda expressions for you.  (You need to catch `ParseException` if you expect the possibility of invalid input).

For formatting the key, you can probably just pass it in directly to the `Html.Encode` method, as its default string representation is something like `{ ID = 1, Name = Test }`.  If that's good enough then I would leave it alone, otherwise you'll have to use Reflection to parse out the individual key properties and property values.

Edit: You can use that library anywhere, if you download the samples you'll see that it is just a source code file.

Comment: What would be the best practice? Should I compile the .CS file separatly? or should I just include it in my own project?

Comment: @Nate Bross: There's no specific best practice; if you foresee the possibility that you might reuse the functionality in a different app, then compile it as a separate library (there's already a `.sln` for you to do that), otherwise either way works.  It's MSPL so you can basically do anything you want with it; the only thing you can't do is redistribute the source file itself without the copyright line at the top.

Comment: OK, call me stupid, but I cannot get this code to work in the View, it works in my Controller, but I can't figure out how to add the `using System.Linq.Dynamic` to the view and `<%@ Import ... %>` isn't working either is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Nate Bross: If you plan to use this on multiple pages, it's probably best to add the assembly and namespace to the web.config file. See here: http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/753705.aspx (the sections you care about are `system.web/pages/namespaces` and `system.web/compilation/assemblies`. If that's not working... post the code/config you used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Linq:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Is this library production ready? Is it free to use in closed source apps?

Comment: IMHO libraries aren't production ready until YOU write tests to cover your usage scenarios.

Comment: @jfar Do you really write tests to verify that System.String works before you use String objects in production?