# Create GroupBy Statments Dynamically By Strings Array - Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I've got an action which loads an array of strings which were checked by thier appropriate checkboxes on the page:

```
        public ActionResult Test1(string[] checked_strings)
```

I would like to use this strings which are equal on their name to the entities which i want to create a groupby statement dynamically.

Which will go on something like this:

```
            bool bChecked = Request.Form["checked_strings"].Contains("true");
            cmpqry =   from x in checked_strings
                       from y in typeof(Company).GetProperties()
                       where y.Name == x.ToString()
     // Create the groupby statement for the properties matched with the strings //
```

Any idea how to pull this over?

cmpqry holds the IEnumarable list(later returned to view) of the model's class.

Comment: Dynamic linq may be your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448611/dynamic-linq-group-by-query-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Already tried that and I can't convert it back to the EF model and list it properly to the view.
If you think it's possible i'd like an example.. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't manage to use the "GroupBy" of dynamic linq, it throws exeption as from this example :
 var groups = Model.GroupBy("SomeColumn, SomeOtherColumn")

even after i've added the library file DynamicLibrary.cs -
Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code sample that works - you should be able to supply the fields you want to group on in the order you want them to be grouped:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string SubBranchName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies grouping to the collection of elements using the selectors specified
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TElement">Type of the element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="elements">Elements to be grouped</param>
    /// <param name="groupSelectors">Selectors, or properties to be grouped on</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
        params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
    {
        if (groupSelectors.Length > 0)
        {
            var selector = groupSelectors.First();

            //reduce the list recursively until zero
            var nextSelectors = groupSelectors.Skip(1).ToArray();
            return
                elements.GroupBy(selector).Select(
                    g => new GroupResult
                    {
                        Key = g.Key,
                        Items = g,
                        SubGroups = g.GroupByMany(nextSelectors)
                    });
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class GroupResult
    {
        public object Key { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GroupResult> SubGroups { get; set; }
    }
}



//Your usage of the GroupByMany
IEnumerable<Company> list = new List<Company>
 {new Company{CompanyID = 1, CompanyName = "Company1", ProductName = "Product1", SubBranchName = "SB1"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 2, CompanyName = "Company1", ProductName = "Product2", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 3, CompanyName = "Company1", ProductName = "Product3", SubBranchName = "SB1"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 4, CompanyName = "Company2", ProductName = "Product4", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 5, CompanyName = "Company2", ProductName = "Product1", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 6, CompanyName = "Company2", ProductName = "Product2", SubBranchName = "SB1"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 7, CompanyName = "Company2", ProductName = "Product3", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 8, CompanyName = "Company3", ProductName = "Product4", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 9, CompanyName = "Company3", ProductName = "Product3", SubBranchName = "SB1"},
 new Company{CompanyID = 10, CompanyName = "Company3", ProductName = "Product2", SubBranchName = "SB2"},
 };

    var groupedByProductNameThenSubBranchName = list.GroupByMany(p => p.ProductName, p => p.SubBranchName);

    foreach (var groupResult in groupedByProductNameThenSubBranchName)
    {
        foreach (var result in groupResult.SubGroups)
        {
            foreach (var groupResult1 in result.Items)
            {
                Company company = groupResult1 as Company;
                Debug.Print(String.Format("ProductName: {0}, SubBranchName: {1}", company.ProductName, company.SubBranchName));
            }
        }
    }

    var groupedBySubBranchNameThenCompany = list.GroupByMany(p => p.SubBranchName, p => p.CompanyName);

    foreach (var groupResult in groupedBySubBranchNameThenCompany)
    {
        foreach (var result in groupResult.SubGroups)
        {
            foreach (var groupResult1 in result.Items)
            {
                Company company = groupResult1 as Company;
                Debug.Print(String.Format("SubBranchName: {0}, CompanyName: {1}", company.SubBranchName, company.CompanyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

The first "foreach" prints out

```
ProductName: Product1, SubBranchName: SB1
ProductName: Product1, SubBranchName: SB2
ProductName: Product2, SubBranchName: SB2
ProductName: Product2, SubBranchName: SB2
ProductName: Product2, SubBranchName: SB1
ProductName: Product3, SubBranchName: SB1
ProductName: Product3, SubBranchName: SB1
ProductName: Product3, SubBranchName: SB2
ProductName: Product4, SubBranchName: SB2
ProductName: Product4, SubBranchName: SB2
```

The second "foreach" prints out

```
SubBranchName: SB1, CompanyName: Company1
SubBranchName: SB1, CompanyName: Company1
SubBranchName: SB1, CompanyName: Company2
SubBranchName: SB1, CompanyName: Company3
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company1
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company2
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company2
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company2
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company3
SubBranchName: SB2, CompanyName: Company3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe use `IQueryable<TElement>` and `Expression<Func<TElement, object>>` to be able to group "natively" and hook into the expression tree built and sent back to the DB?

Comment: And if I want to groupBy only one group without subgroups?

Comment: Well it's awesome evgeny, How do you pass the GroupByMany(p => p.DynamicField1, p => p.DynamicField2 ... p => p.DynamicFieldN);and do all the subgroup mining later dynamically? with for loop from strings or what? , The primary cause is to make generate a Company after the groupby and pass it to the view. thanks alot!

Comment: Another important thing, When you use:  ---
Company company = groupResult1 as Company; --- The whole company is filled and not only the fields which i wanted to groupby with, How can the company entity only have only the proper fields and leave the other null, etc? , Or should i just cluase the visibility for those fields in the view(The load time is better if only the needed grouped fields will be loaded!)

Comment: Also the company should be filled and not overided on the first raw every time.

Comment: If i attemp :: Company company = groupResult1 as Company;
                        context.Companies.Add(company);
                        context.SaveChanges();
--- I Will get "Invalid column name 'ProductName'" exception thrown, How do i add all those grouped values into a Company entity i can list to view?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly how relevant this is to your particular problem, but if you have a field you want to group your data on you can write a query similar to the following, which groups the blog posts on the year they were created in

```
var results = from allPosts in db.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.DateCreated)
              group allPosts by allPosts.DateCreated.Year into postsByYear;
```

The "results" here is the enumeration of groups - in this case, posts published in a certain year.

This can be further extended to create child groups within the "first level" - posts by the month groups similar to

```
var results = from allPosts in db.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.DateCreated)
              group allPosts by allPosts.DateCreated.Year into postsByYear

              select new
              {
                  postsByYear.Key,
                  SubGroups = from yearLevelPosts in postsByYear
                              group yearLevelPosts by yearLevelPosts.DateCreated.Month into postsByMonth;
              };
```

Now the SubGroups is the enumeration of posts within the month.
There is more information here (may be very helpful)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2007/12/22/playing-with-linq-grouping-groupbymany.aspx

and here (my application of the previous link to a particular problem I had)

http://www.ynegve.info/Post/156/implementing-a-tree-view-small-case-study

If that looks like what you need, but you still can't make it work, please post more info about your model.

Comment: Hey Evgeny, Thank you for your time.
I've made a more well explained post here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1885915.aspx/1?GroupBy+changing+number+of+columns+Dynamically+

Basicly, I have several fields that i want to pass as variable to the groupBy clause instead of hard-coded grouping by casing every possible scenerio.

To be able to do something like : 
IEnumerable<Company> afs = cmpqry.GroupBy("CompanyName", "SubBranchName", "ProductName");

and afterward when users checks different fields ill be able to pass other values:

IEnumerable<Company> afs = cmpqry.GroupBy("CompanyName", "SomeName");