# How to perform group by operation in dataTable using multiple columns in dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following data in my dataTable
[image]

I get a grouping columns dynamically(Name of the bank,No of offices , No of Employees,Business per Employee,Profit per employee)

Now I want to group the data in 5 level (i.e Name of the bank=>No of offices => No of Employees => Business per Employee =>Profit per employee)

How can i do this using linq in dynamically?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: take a look at here it might helps you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10258/

Comment: show the code you have so far

Comment: So do you want to group by 5 fixed fields or do you want to do it dynamically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ Group By Query in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448611/dynamic-linq-group-by-query-in-asp-net-mvc) (and many more).

Comment: I want to do it with  dynamic fields

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given any code or entities so i can demonstrate it by an example

```
var result = YourList.GroupBy(x=> new { x.NameOfBank, x.Noofoffices,x.Employees,x.BusinessperEmployee,x.Profitperemployee })
```